# include() inside function: return works unexpectedly

Tags: php, return, external

So, I want to have my class include another file which in turn executes the return statement...

```
class layout {
    public static function make($file) {
        include $file;
    }
}
```

I have a `mylayout.layout.php`

```
<?php 
return true;
```

and then I do

```
echo layout::make('mylayout.layout.php');
```

Result is `null`

Comment: Why do you want to return at first line?

Comment: You can have a return statement. But it will not be the return statement of the function that includes. (as you may expect)

Comment: Is this a prima facie case for using traits? I don't really see their value, but this might be an appropriate circumstance

Answer (score 4):

`include` is not equal to copy and pasting of code. You do not `return` anything from the `layout::make` method, so nothing (`null`) is returned. You *have* to write `return` in the code in your class to return something from the method.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply on IRC. Problem is, the return from the external file goes to the include function. So I have to return the value of (include 'mylayout.layout.php');

I also found this post by reformatting my question for google: [Return from include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314162/return-from-include-file)