# How to include return values from a different file in a variable

Tags: php, javascript

I can return a value from embedded php within the variable (as below), but in this case I would like to get the output of a php file e.g. result.php.

```
var jsVar = "<?php echo 'thisisfromphp' ?>";
```

So running 'result.php' would produce a result to be returned. How could I grab this result from result.php and use it as the variable - I was thinking something like:

```
var jsVar = "<?php echo result.php ?>";
```

P.S. I would embed the php code from result.php in the variable (as above) but it all gets to messy..

Comment: IIRC you can use `include` and it should work as long as you explicitly return a value in the file.

Comment: Hi Mahn, thanks, but could you provide an example pleasE?

Comment: Sure, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1314198/1329367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is refactor your code. Don't have `result.php` echo something out that you try and capture. That's not resuable code. Abstract whatever it does into a function that can be reused, then you can just `require "result.php"` and later `callYourFunction()` to get the desired output.

If, however, you are insistent on doing it this way (which, again, I advise against), you could:

```
ob_start();
require_once 'result.php';
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// later...
var jsVar = <?php echo json_encode($contents); ?>
```