# includer vs. return include

Tags: php, include, loader

when you need to include a file, simply use "*include file*" and when you need to return a configuration file you must use "*return include file*"...
usually i have a function "**loader( $file , $return = false )**" where I use *$return* to return include, or not.
my question is if there is a problem in keeping return include file even for files that are not configuration:

```
return include "class/view.php"
return include "config/test.php"
```

thank you

Comment: X-Ref: [Return from include file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1314162/367456)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`php.net`](http://php.net/include):

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a
>   warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file,
>   return 1. It is possible to execute a return statement inside an
>   included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return
>   to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values
>   from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you
>   would for a normal function. This is not, however, possible when
>   including remote files unless the output of the remote file has valid
>   PHP start and end tags (as with any local file). You can declare the
>   needed variables within those tags and they will be introduced at
>   whichever point the file was included.

If your `class/view.php` or `config/test.php` uses [`return`](http://php.net/return), then you may keep it. If there is no [`return`](http://php.net/return) in those files, there is no reason, unless you want to prevent current script from further execution.

***Example 1:***

```
<?php
echo 1;  // < executes

return include 'somefile.php';  // < script will end here because of "return"

echo 2;  // < not executes ever
?>
```

***Example 2:***

```
<?php
echo 1;  // < executes

include 'somefile.php';  // < executes

echo 2;  // < executes
?>
```

Comment: even if I run include within a class-function, a file with a return break the chain that could be sequential... nothing would be done after the include, then I think the best choice would be to keep an import classes and import configuration files to where I could handle until the types with more facilities (.php , .ini, ...)correct?
cheers to you too friend

Comment: @PapaCharlie return within function context will not break script execution. Return within script context will. Development choises is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If included file doesn't have `return`, it will just return `1`, so there will be no problem.

Comment: But if you have several returns one by one, only the first file will be included, I think. It depends on where this happens.