# Dynamic load of page content

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I am trying to load my content dynamically via PHP. Here is my code, which for some reason doesnt work. Can you give me some hint, what am I doing wrong?

The goal is :

1. Click on Hypertext in nav
2. Get dynamically content from file page-statistiky in folder /podstranky

Code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?stranka=page-statistiky">statistiky</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['stranka']))
    $stranka = $_GET['stranka'];
else
    $stranka = 'page-statistiky';
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $stranka)) {
    $vlozeno = include('podstranky/' . $stranka . '.php');
    if (!$vlozeno)
        echo('Podstránka nenalezena');
} else
    echo('Neplatný parametr.');?>
```

Comment: What is the issue? Any error? What you want to achieve? The question is incomplete.

Comment: @RajendranNadar I have edited the question, is it clear now?

Comment: include read simple file (php), not force to execute agorithm (in this file)

Comment: Put a ajax call to load data. Else you will be redirected

Comment: What happens when you execute this code

Comment: You can redirect target php, instead of include

Comment: @Akintunde I get "Neplatný parametr" code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regex doesn't include provision for the dash i.e. `-`'
Change this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/', $stranka))`
```

to

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/', $stranka))
```

Comment: A return with `include` is possible:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1314198/1461181

Comment: I stand corrected. You learn something new everyday :).

The way @ragulin is using that feature seems to be still incorrect. Based on PHP manual, you need to use this in this way `if ((include 'vars.php') == TRUE)` and not expect include to return value as a function.