# include array from file is not working on php 7.4

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem with include array from file. On php 7.3 was good...

Included file:

```
<?
return ['key' => 'value'];
```

My controller:

```
<?
$data = include 'file.php';
var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
['key' => 'value'];
int(1)
```

I want get my array from file without output when including.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: If you don't want any output, then lose the `var_dump()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly its working on php 7.3

Comment: @RiggsFolly - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314162/return-from-include-file.

Comment: @PatrickQ I want get array with data from file, but I get int(1)

Comment: `its working on php 7.3` impossible, because you dont have defined `$data`

Comment: @Zeljka its real...

Comment: Try using `<?php` at the start in case `<?` is not recognised

Comment: @NigelRen Another good day. Learned something, thanks :) And I can get the above code to work in PHP7.3.13 and PHP7.4.1